# An algorithm for filtering text files

Tags: r, import

Imagine you have a `.txt` file of the following structure:

```
>>> header
>>> header
>>> header
K L M
200 0.1 1
201 0.8 1
202 0.01 3
...
800 0.4 2
>>> end of file
50 0.1 1
75 0.78 5
...
```

I would like to read all the data except lines denoted by `>>>` and lines below the `>>> end of file` line.
So far I've solved this using `read.table(comment.char = ">", skip = x, nrow = y)` (`x` and `y` are currently fixed). This reads the data between the header and `>>> end of file`.

However, I would like to make my function a bit more plastic regarding the number of rows. Data may have values larger than 800, and consequently more rows.

I could `scan` or `readLines` the file and see which row corresponds to the `>>> end of file` and calculate the number of lines to be read. What approach would you use?

Comment: Please provide some dummy data. =)

Comment: @aL3xa: is the snippet already shown insufficient?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
Lines <- readLines("foo.txt")
markers <- grepl(">", Lines)
want <- rle(markers)$lengths[1:2]
want <- seq.int(want[1] + 1, sum(want), by = 1)
read.table(textConnection(Lines[want]), sep = " ", header = TRUE)
```

Which gives:

```
> read.table(textConnection(Lines[want]), sep = " ", header = TRUE)
    K    L M
1 200 0.10 1
2 201 0.80 1
3 202 0.01 3
4 800 0.40 2
```

On the data snippet you provide (in file `foo.txt`, and after removing the ... lines).

Comment: +1, nice to learn about `rle`, which I haven't used before. I'm wondering though if there's a way to modify the definition of `read.table` (and/or `scan` and/or `readLines`), by adding an optional `EOF` argument so that it bails when it encounters the `EOF` string. That way we could do this in one pass rather than 2.

Comment: EOF argument would be a nice addition.

Comment: I was hoping there would be a way to add an optional EOF arg to the source definition for `scan`, but it calls `.Internal(scan...)`, so the only way is to change the internal (C?) code for scan...

Comment: A tiny side-effect of the textConnection() within a function (lapply) is that connections get gc()-ed, which produces an irritating warning (harmless). This can be solved with closeAllConnections() after a textConnection() call.

Comment: @Roman; good point. If I were using the above a lot, I'd wrap it in a function, save the output of `con <- textConnection(Lines[want])` and include a `on.exit(close(con))` in the function body to ensure only the generated connection was closed, whenever the function exited, normally or abnormally.

Answer (score 11):

Here are a couple of ways.

1) `readLine` reads in the lines of the file into `L` and sets `skip` to the number of lines to skip at the beginning and `end.of.file` to the line number of the row marking the end of the data.  The `read.table` command then uses these two variables to re-read the data.

```
File <- "foo.txt"

L <- readLines(File)
skip <- grep("^.{0,2}[^>]", L)[1] - 1
end.of.file <- grep("^>>> end of file", L)

read.table(File, header = TRUE, skip = skip, nrow = end.of.file - skip - 2)
```

A variation would be to use `textConnection` in place of `File` in the `read.table` line:

```
read.table(textConnection(L), header = TRUE, 
   skip = skip, nrow = end.of.file - skip - 2)
```

2) Another possibility is to use sed or awk/gawk.  Consider this one line gawk program. The program exits if it sees the line marking the end of the data; otherwise, it skips the current line if that line starts with >>> and if neither of those happen it prints the line.  We can pipe `foo.txt` through the gawk program and read it using `read.table`.

```
cat("/^>>> end of file/ { exit }; /^>>>/ { next }; 1\n", file = "foo.awk")
read.table(pipe('gawk -f foo.awk foo.txt'), header = TRUE)
```

A variation of this is that we could omit the `/^>>>/ {next};` portion of the gawk program, which skips over the `>>>` lines at the beginning, and use `comment = ">" in the`read.table` call instead.

Comment: The awk/gawk solution would be very handy if you couldn't foresee the structure of your file in advance.