# how can i read a csv file containing some additional text data

Tags: r, csv

I need to read a csv file in R. But the file contains some text information in some rows instead of comma values. So i cannot read that file using read.csv(fileName) method. 
The content of the file is as follows:

```
name:russel date:21-2-1991
abc,2,saa
anan,3,ds
ama,ds,az
,,

name:rus date:23-3-1998
snans,32,asa
asa,2,saz
```

I need to store only values of each name,date pair as data frame. To do that how can i read that file?

Actually my required output is

```
>dataFrame1
    abc,2,saa
    anan,3,ds
    ama,ds,az
>dataFrame2
    snans,32,asa
    asa,2,saz
```

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/q/4629115/1290420

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can read the data with `scan` and use `grep` and `sub` functions to extract the important values.

The text:

```
text <- "name:russel date:21-2-1991
abc,2,saa
anan,3,ds
ama,ds,az
,,

name:rus date:23-3-1998
snans,32,asa
asa,2,saz"
```

These commands generate a data frame with name and date values.

```
# read the text
lines <- scan(text = text, what = character())
# find strings staring with 'name' or 'date'
nameDate <- grep("^name|^date", lines, value = TRUE)
# extract the values
values <- sub("^name:|^date:", "", nameDate)
# create a data frame
dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(values, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE,
                            dimnames = list(NULL, c("name", "date"))))
```

The result:

```
> dat
    name      date
1 russel 21-2-1991
2    rus 23-3-1998
```

---

**Update**

To extract the values from the strings, which do not contain name and date information, the following commands can be used:

```
# read data
lines <- readLines(textConnection(text))
# split lines
splitted <- strsplit(lines, ",")
# find positions of 'name' lines
idx <- grep("^name", lines)[-1]
# create grouping variable
grp <- cut(seq_along(lines), c(0, idx, length(lines)))
# extract values
values <- tapply(splitted, grp, FUN = function(x)
                                        lapply(x, function(y)
                                                    if (length(y) == 3) y))
create a list of data frames
dat <- lapply(values, function(x) as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(x),
                                                       ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)))
```

The result:

```
> dat
$`(0,7]`
    V1 V2  V3
1  abc  2 saa
2 anan  3  ds
3  ama ds  az

$`(7,9]`
     V1 V2  V3
1 snans 32 asa
2   asa  2 saz
```

Comment: sir.this answer is very useful for me. But the actual output i required is different.please see the edit in the question.

Answer (score 4):

I would read the entire file first as a list of characters, i.e. a string for each line in the file, this can be done using `readLines`. Next you have to find the places where the data for a new date starts, i.e. look for `,,`, see `grep` for that. Then take the first entry of each data block, e.g. using `str_extract` from the `stringr` package. Finally, you need split all the remaing data strings, see `strsplit` for that.