# delete some rows from a character array in R

Tags: r, csv

I have a file containing some csv datas and some text information.
The file contains the following data:

```
name:russel date:21-2-1991
abc,2,saa
anan,3,ds
ama,ds,az
,,

name:rus date:23-3-1998
snans,32,asa
asa,2,saz
```

Because of it contains some extra text information i cannot read that file using read.csv() method in R. So i read that file using

```
text <- readLines("samplepf.csv")
lines <- scan(text = text, what = character())
```

Now i want to remove all the unwanted information from the character array "lines". I want only the data in the csv format.
what is the code i need to use to check all the data very quickly?

Comment: I recommend pre-processing the data by eliminating lines that do not contain commas (should be easy to automate), then load into R with read.csv(....,na.strings="").

Comment: but actualy i need to read those information also. thats why i use the readLine(). But after getting those information, i need to remove that information from "lines".

Comment: @DinoopNair why are asking the same question twice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15402473/how-can-i-read-a-csv-file-containing-some-additional-text-data !! this one is very similar to your previous question.

Comment: @agstudy:only the data is same.my question is different.

Comment: @DinoopNair, my answer doesn't solve your problem?

Comment: @DinoopNair I don't see any effort to understand the answers. I find them very clear. You have special file format, you need to read the file with `readLines` or `scan` then treat it using `strsplit` or ``sub|grep|gsub..`. That's about it. I dwonvote and I ask to close this question as too localized question ( or do it for me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your other lines don't have a `,`, I'd do something like this:

```
tt <- readLines("my_file")
tt.con <- textConnection(tt[grepl(",", tt)])
my.dat <- read.table(tt.con, , sep=",")
close(tt.con)
> my.dat
#      V1 V2  V3
# 1   abc  2 saa
# 2  anan  3  ds
# 3   ama ds  az
# 4             
# 5 snans 32 asa
# 6   asa  2 saz
```